# Prove that $f$ is bounded when higher derivative is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:(-2019,2020) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is $1000$ times differentiable and $f^{(1000)}$ is bounded then also $f$ is bounded. If $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ it is also right?

**My try:**

$f^{(1000)}$ bounded $\Rightarrow$ $f^{(999)}$ has Lipschitz continuity $\Rightarrow$ $|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|\le L$

Then I tried to use this for $f^{(998)}, f^{(997)},\dots,f^{(0)}=f$. However I don't know how I can do it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Just prove that if $f$ is differentiable then if $f'$ is bounded, then $f$ is bounded. Now, by induction, if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable, then $f^{(n)}$ is bounded implies $f$ is bounded

Comment: Now, if we have function from $R$ to $R$, then for example for $f(x) = x$, $f'(x) = 1$ is bounded, but $f$ isn't. Now we see that if we just take $f(x) = x^{1000}$, it's a counterexample.